# How to make operator= accept derivatives of parameter like operator+?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading, assignment-operator, overload-resolution

I don't understand why `a = b` doesn't print out `value from operator= 5` like operator+ (which seems to allows derivatives). Why does it do this instead of allowing derivatives and how can I make it accept derivatives too?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    int value = 5;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void operator=(const A& rhs) {
        std::cout << "value from operator= " << rhs.value << std::endl;
    }
    
    void operator+(const A& rhs) {
        std::cout << "value from operator+ " << rhs.value << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    
    B a;
    B b;
    A c;
    
    std::cout << "testing operator=" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "testing with B:" << std::endl;
    a = b; // doesn't print anything
    std::cout << "testing with A:" << std::endl;
    a = c; // outputs: value from operator= 5
    
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "testing operator+" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "testing with B:" << std::endl;
    a + b; // outputs: value from operator+ 5
    std::cout << "testing with A:" << std::endl;
    a + c; // outputs: value from operator+ 5
    
}
```

Comment: You may want to fix the return type, which for those should `B&` instead of `void`.

Comment: @AlexisWilke This is just a example on the real class it does what it's supposed to but I want it to be able to take derivatives and I don't know how to or why it doesn't.

Comment: It looks like `operator=(const A&)` doesn't override the default generated `operator=(const B&)`. Hence, `a = b;` uses the default generated copy assignment op., and thus, no printing. If that op. is user defined as well your example works as expected: [demo on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e35ccd26389e468) - even with that strange, unusual void return type.

Comment: I forgot to mention, for `a = b`, the default generated `operator=(const B&)` is the better candidate while `operator=(const A&)` would require an implicit conversion. So, it's even not an ambiguity but just a clear choice. Concerning `operator+`, things are much different because there is no default generated candidate around...

Comment: Defining `B a;` when your other class is `A` is a recipe for confusion. Better would be `B b1; B b2; A a;`

Comment: Fun fact: despite your title, your `operator=` does accept derivatives of its parameter, except for `B` (which is the only derived class you checked? Did you jump to an unwarranted generalization?). Ex: `class D : public A {};` then in your function: `D d;` `a = d; // outputs: value from operator= 5`

Comment: The reason that `a = b` doesn't print anything is that there is an implicitly generated copy assignment operator that accepts a (usually `const`) `B &` argument.   Declaring an `operator=(const A &)` in `B` does not change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`B::operator=(const A& rhs)` is not a copy assignment or move assignment operator, so the [implicitly-defined copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Implicitly-defined_copy_assignment_operator) still exists, and has the signature

```cpp
B& operator=(const B&);
```

When doing `a = b`, this operator wins in overload resolution against yours because to call it, no derived-to-base conversion `B -> A` is necessary, unlike for your assignment operator.

One way to have both `B`s and `A`s use this operator is:

```cpp
B& operator=(const A& rhs) {
    std::cout << "value from operator= " << rhs.value << std::endl;
    return *this;
}

B& operator=(const B& rhs) {
    return static_cast<A&>(*this) = rhs;
}
```

More traditionally, `A` should have its own user-defined copy assignment operator and `B` would forward to it through `return A::operator=(rhs);`